How to use localStorage in Angular 18 HttpInterceptorFn?
I'm new in Angular and I'm trying to get access and refresh tokens from localStorage in http interceptor, but I'm getting this error: Page /admin did not render in 30 seconds.
auth.interceptor.ts:
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';

export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access');
  const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh');

  return next(req);
};

profile.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { User } from '../../models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrl: './profile.component.scss'
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User | null = null;
  isFailed = false;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private titleService: Title) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap) => {
      const username = String(paramMap.get('username'));

      this.userService.getUser(username).subscribe({
        next: (user) => {
          this.isFailed = false;
          this.user = user;
          this.titleService.setTitle(`${this.user.display_name || this.user.username} profile`);
        },
        error: () => {
          this.isFailed = true;
        }
      });
    });
  }
}


If I remove localStorage.getItem() functions then error disappears.

You can't use localStorage if you use prerendering.

@MatthieuRiegler So I can't get tokens from localStorage in interceptor?

You probably don't need prerendering.
disable it by removing prerender: true from your angular.json.

You can use localstorage inside the web like below. After next render hook will make sure your code executed once it got rendered on browser.
afterNextRender(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('my-key', 'My value');
});

If you want to use in server side you need to add polyfills by following below steps
npm i localstorage-polyfill --save

Add these two lines inside server.ts file
import 'localstorage-polyfill'

global['localStorage'] = localStorage

Then you can use localstorage as well inside server as well

You can try this
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';

export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // Only run this code in the browser
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access');
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh');
  }
  return next(req);
};

